# How to display a JavaScript result as a paragraph?

Tags: javascript

I have been working with a javascript that will calculate BMI of a person. But with the BMI result, I want to display specific comments of specific result group. How can I do that?
Here is the script:

```
<script>
    <!--
        function calculateBmi() 
            {
                var weight = document.bmiForm.weight.value
                var height = document.bmiForm.height.value
                    if(weight > 0 && height > 0)
                        {   
                            var stadnardwight1 = 19*height/100*height/100
                                document.bmiForm.weight1.value = stadnardwight1

                            var stadnardwight2 = 25*height/100*height/100
                                document.bmiForm.weight2.value = stadnardwight2

                            var finalBmi = weight/(height/100*height/100)
                                document.bmiForm.bmi.value = finalBmi
                                    if(finalBmi < 19)
                                        {
                                            document.bmiForm.meaning.value = "That you are too thin."
                                        }
                                    if(finalBmi > 19 && finalBmi < 25)
                                        {
                                            document.bmiForm.meaning.value = "That you are healthy."
                                        }
                                    if(finalBmi > 25)
                                        {
                                            document.bmiForm.meaning.value = "That you have overweight."
                                        }
                        }
                else
                    {
                        alert("Please Fill in everything correctly")
                    }
            }
    //-->
    </script>

    <form name="bmiForm">
    Your Weight(kg): <input type="text" name="weight" size="10"><br />
    Your Height(cm): <input type="text" name="height" size="10"><br />
    <input type="button" value="Calculate BMI" onClick="calculateBmi()"><br />
    Your BMI: <input type="text" name="bmi" size="10"><br />
    This Means: <input type="text" name="meaning" size="25"><br />
    Your weight should be between: <input type="text" name="weight1" size="10"> to <input type="text" name="weight2" size="10"> kg<br />
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
    </form>
```

Here, meaning value is displayed by a text input from. But how can I display it as a paragraph, not as a text input?

Thanks in advance for helping.

**Note:** The meaning will change according to the 3 different categories of results.
*It would be very helpful if you please give an example of line of code for the solution.*

Comment: Use <p> to display text instead of <input>

Comment: Thanks. Problem solved.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an 'input' tag for meaning, use a 'span' tag, and set the innerHtml of that span to the content you want.